# Difference between ' and " on command line (bash)?

Tags: bash, shell, special-characters, quoting

I used to use `''` and `""` (single and double-quotes) interchangeably on the command line, but I recently noticed that `'$HOME/some/dir'` is not expanded, while `"$HOME/some/dir"` is. I searched around a little bit and found that `""` allows *some* protection of special characters, while `''` allows full protection. So what other characters are protected by `''` and not `""`?

EDIT: What are *practical* situations in which these differences might be significant?

Comment: Have a look on to this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20034/differences-between-doublequotes-singlequotes-and-backticks-on-comma) in StackExchange's AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at the bash man page. There's an entire section on quoting. Because this licensed under the GFDL, which is not compatible with the CC-BY-SA license used here, I won't quote the whole thing, but really [reading that is the most definitive answer](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting).

In summary, single quotes stop all interpretation -- the string is rendered literally. Double quotes leave `$` (dollar sign), ` (backquote) as special, and `\` (backslash) as special when followed by certain other characters. And `!` will be treated specially if the history expansion feature is enabled (which it is by default).

In practical use, the `$` is the big deal, as one often may want the various expansions it enables to (variables and more), while still preventing the shell from muddling most of the command line.

Comment: Is this form of quoting standard across shells, or is it bash-specific?

Comment: It is bash-specific. Plain `/bin/sh` bourne shell is similar, but bash can do more things so it works slightly differently. Same with ksh, which is also _mostly kinda_ bourne-like. Tcsh and other csh-style shells work differently.

Comment: @apoorv020: This is common to all Bourne-style shells (Bourne, POSIX, ash, ksh, bash, zsh, …), apart from the treatment of `!` as a history character which is specific to bash. Csh and fish have different rules.

Comment: The parameters `*` and `@` get special treatment inside double quotes, but this means that `"$*"` and `"$@"` are special (actually only `"$@"` is special; `$*` and `$@` are special when unquoted) . Something like `"@*"` is perfectly ordinary, just a literal two-character string.

Answer (score 2):

While single quotes preserve the literal value of all characters they enclose,

double quotes differ in that they do not preserve  the literal value of the dollar sign , $, the back-ticks, - - , and the backslash , .

When enclosed with double quotes, the dollar sign and back-ticks preserve their special meaning , and the special meaning of the backslash character is only retained when it precedes a dollar sign , back-tick , double quote, backslash , or newline.

Example:

```
[user@localhost~]$ echo '$HOME'
$HOME
[user@localhost~]$ echo '`pwd`'
`pwd`
[user@localhost~]$ echo '"Hello world"'
"Hello world"

[user@localhost~]$ echo "$HOME"
/home/user
[user@localhost~]$ echo "`pwd`"
/home/user

[user@localhost~]$ echo ""Hello world""
Hello world
[user@localhost~]$ echo "\$HOME"
$HOME
[user@localhost~]$ echo "\`pwd\`"
`pwd`
[user@localhost~]$ echo "\"Hello ,world\""
"Hello, world"
```