# How to use a value returned by a script in grep filter?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, grep

I'm on FreeBSD's csh.
I want to form a row with domains of one user and then use this row to filter exim maillog to get only mail from/to this user's domains.

I wrote a script to form a row from a list of DirectAdmin-domains:

```
#!/bin/sh
user="some-user"

    list=$(cat /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/$user/domains.list)
    domaincount=$(echo $list|wc -w)
    echo $list| tr ' ' '|'
```

Executing this script returns rows with domains like this: `'domain.com'` or this: `'domain1.com|domain2.net'`

Now I want to use this as an argument to `grep`, but

```
cat /var/log/exim/mainlog |egrep `/path/to/rowscript`
```

returns nothing, while replacing manually `/path/to/rowscript` with its result returns what I want to see.

Tried to use

```
grep -E "`/path/to/rowscript`", 
egrep '`/path/to/rowscript`' 
egrep `/bin/sh /path/to/rowscript`
egrep $(/path/to/rowscript)
    getting "Illegal variable name."
```

etc., but still no luck.

BTW, `date` in backticks works well:

```
cat /var/log/exim/mainlog | grep `date +%Y-%m-%d`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script should not output single quotes. When you write

```
egrep 'foo|bar'
```

the single quotes are part of the shell syntax. They protect the characters inside them against expansion. If single quotes appear in the output of your script, they'll be taken as ordinary characters. Simply omit them.

There's a far easier way to write your script: replace newlines by pipe symbols, and remove the last one.

```
list=$(</usr/local/directadmin/data/users/$user/domains.list tr '\n' '|')
echo "${list%|}"
```

You don't need to do that if you're looking for a fixed set of strings. Instead, use the `-F` option to `grep` to tell it to look for fixed strings, and the `-f` option to tell it to read a list of patterns from a file.

```
grep -Ff /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/bob/domains.list
```

Note that if you have `domain.com` in that file, the search will also return hits for longer strings such as `otherdomain.com`. So you may want to use your script to build a pattern that has anchors at the beginning and at the end, so avoid spurious matching. I don't know what kind of punctuation the exim log has; for example, if the names are surrounded by whitespace, you'd want something like

```
#!/bin/sh
list=$(</usr/local/directadmin/data/users/$1/domains.list tr '\n' '|')
echo " (${list%|}) "
```

and call it as

```
</var/log/exim/mainlog grep -E `/path/to/rowscript bob`
```

Or make the script call grep:

```
#!/bin/sh
shift
list=$(</usr/local/directadmin/data/users/$1/domains.list tr '\n' '|')
grep -E " (${list%|}) " -- "$@"
```

called as

```
</var/log/exim/mainlog /path/to/rowscript bob
```

Comment: 1) I've already tested a script, that I posted first and simplified it. 2) `Simply omit them.` Okay, I tried to omit them earlier and now too. Then I added  ticks to egrep '`/script/row`' and still have no luck 3) Thanks for `grep -Ff`! It works pretty good.

Comment: @Drey Your revised version still has single quotes: change `echo "'"$list"'"` to `echo "$list"`.

Comment: I removed these quotes from script already, but still can't use script output as a filter

Comment: @Drey What does your input file look like? What does your script's output look like (and what version of your script are you using, you've made several changes and I've lost track)?

Comment: Now I'm using this script: `#!/bin/sh
list=$(cat /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/bob/domains.list)
echo $list| tr ' ' '|'`
and trying to invocate it like this: `cat /var/log/exim/mainlog | grep 2011-11-13 | grep -E '\`/scripts/domainsrow\`'`. Script itself executes good but still can't be used as a filter string.

Comment: @Drey Again, drop the single quotes: ``… | grep -E `/scripts/domainsrow` `` See [Difference between ' and " on command line (bash)?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7574) (but note that csh has different rules, so also read the csh manual).

Comment: Weird, but you're right! when using script output as a filter for grep you don't need single quotes, but when you just typing filter you must use them to escape pipe symbol. Now it's clear. Thank you for your time  and patience!