# Replace a number with sed/awk

Tags: awk, sed, scripting

I need to replace a number using a script, I am using the following command

```
 for ((i=1; i=<10, i=i+1))
sed '244s/0.8/(0.$i)/' analyze3big.f >> $i.f
```

But for some reason it does not work.

Comment: Well, how does "it does not work" manifest? What did you expect to happen and what exactly happens instead?

Comment: See [Difference between ' and " on command line (bash)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7574/difference-between-and-on-command-line-bash)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between ' and " on command line (bash)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7574/difference-between-and-on-command-line-bash)

Answer (score 2):

Strong quotes (`'`) prevent variable expansion.  Use weak quotes (`"`) instead:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    sed "244s/0\.8/(0.$i)/" analyze3big.f >> $i.f 
done
```